# Reading from text area by line and assigning variables

Tags: java, textarea

I need to append  variables to each line of text from a `TextArea`. The `TextArea` is coded, and works perfectly. I can retrieve  information from the `TextArea` by using `TextArea.getText();`
To break it apart, I am trying to use a `BufferedReader`. Unfortunately, this does not work. Is there a different way of doing this?                   Here is an example of how the information needs to be written in the text area:

"workerName"

"workerDepartment"

"workerNumber"

```
BufferedReader inStream= new BufferedReader 
(new InputStreamReader(TextArea.getText()));

String workerName = "";

String workerDepartment = "";

int workerNumber = 0;

String line = inStream.readLine();            

while (line != null) {                        

 workerName = line;

 line = inStream.readLine();               

 workerDepartment = line;

 line = inStream.readLine();               

 workerNumber = Integer.parseInt(line);

 }

 inStream.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the lines are separated by any delimiter(for example newline, comma...) , then use split method of String and put the delimiter

```
String[] lines = TextArea.getText().split("\n");

//then you can access your array
String workerName = lines[0];
String workerDepartment = lines[1];
// and so on
```

Also you need to check array size before getting the value to prevent ArrayOutOfIndexException, for example if there are two lines only then you should not call lines[2], so do the check:

```
   if ( lines.length < 3 ) {
      // input is not complete, show error message
   }
   else {
      // do your splitting and reading values
   }
```